# Vector push back operation with pointer

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a vector pointer and trying to push back a value. It seems that this operation needs round braces. Why does one need round braces?

```
void foo(vector<int> *v1)
{
*v1.push_back(1); //(*v1).push_back(1); 
}

int main()
{
vector<int> A;
foo(&A);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because that's how the operators bind. You can also use `->`. Or avoid pointers when a reference will work, and work better.

Comment: void foo(vector<int>& v1)  is better. Call it with foo(A);

Comment: The behavior is the same as for all other pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Operator precedence.

Member access (`.push_back`) has higher precedence than indirection/dereference (`*v1`), so `*v1.push_back(1)` is equivalent to `*(v1.push_back(1))`. This is not what you want.

The parentheses in `(*v1)` give the expression higher precedence from left-to-right than the member access, thus why it's valid and equivalent to `->`.

`v1->` is syntactic sugar for `(*v1).`

[Operator Precedence Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: "v1-> is syntactic sugar for (*v1)." -- or the obverse. Neither seems particularly sweet.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I'm just the messenger.

Comment: @JiveDadson What's unsweet about `v1->`? `v1` is a pointer, `->` is looks like an arrow that points. It's the operator used all the time with pointers, it should be natural to most programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this example:

```
int a[] = {100, 70, 55, 12};
int* pA = &a[0];

*pA++; // you think 100 + 1 but a[0 + 1] so result: 70
```

Above you de-referenced pA after incrementing the address it points to not the value it stores in the address it points to.

So you need `()`:

```
(*pA)++;
```

- TIP: To change `operator precedence` use parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to dereference the pointer to vector in order to be able to call it's member function, hence the syntax:

```
(*v1).push_back(1);
```

The same can be achieved by using the *arrow* `->` operator:

```
v1->push_back(1);
```

Alternatively pass the argument by reference:

```
void foo(vector<int>& v1) {
    v1.push_back(1);
}

int main() {
    vector<int> A;
    foo(A);
}
```